# Changing terminal user

Tags: users

I got a laptop where user1 as already there, now I created user2 and deleted user1, still when I am opening terminal it shows:

```
user2@user1:~$
```

I want to make it like this:

```
user2@user2:~$
```

How can I do it?
I am using Ubuntu version 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string after the "@" is the name of the host. To change this you have to change the name of your computer.